# python - non blocking rest api with n workers and zmq

Tags: python, multithreading, zeromq, aiohttp, pyzmq

I'm try to setup a rest API which I can call N times at once, and it'd queue those calls and distribute the work to M workers

Here's what I have:

rest API forwarding data to the zmq workers:

```
import json

import time
import zmq
import asyncio

url_client = "tcp://localhost:5559"
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect(url_client)

from aiohttp import web
import json

async def process_orders(req):
    response_obj = { 'status' : 'success' }
    print('processing')
    body = await req.json()

    socket.send(str(body).encode())
    response = socket.recv()
    
    return web.Response(text=json.dumps(response.decode()))

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_post('/process_orders', process_orders)

web.run_app(app, port=6666)
```

workers:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import threading
import time
import zmq
import json

from order_manager import parseResponse
import time
import threading
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()

def worker():
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.connect('inproc://workers')
    while True:
        msg = socket.recv_string()
        parsed_request = json.loads(msg.replace("'", '"'))
        res = parseResponse(parsed_request) # working part, takes time
        print('Received request:')
        # time.sleep(1)
        socket.send_string(str({"status":'ok'}))

url_client = 'tcp://*:5559'
clients = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
clients.bind(url_client)
workers = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
workers.bind('inproc://workers')

for _ in range(4): # 4 workers
    thread = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    thread.start()

zmq.device(zmq.QUEUE, clients, workers)
```

When I send 10 requests at once, it will make 10 calls to the aiohttp route, but then only dispatch the work sequentially.
Submit #1, wait until over, sumbit #2...
instead I'm looking to submit #1 & #2 & ... & #M (number of workers) and managing the outputs as they come, while resubmiting work to idle workers

How could I do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here

```
socket.send(str(body).encode())
response = socket.recv()
```

You are using blocking functions.

Instead use the [asyncio supported version of pyzmq.](https://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/zmq.asyncio.html#module-zmq.asyncio)